# Upgrade dependencies version in @angular/compiler-cli

Tags: angular

How can i upgrade the "ansi-regex" dependencies version in @angular/compiler-cli and @angular/localize in my angular project? The below are in package-lock.json. If I manually update in package-lock.json, it will be overwritten if i run npm install.

How should i upgrade ansi-regex to version 5.0.3 for @angular/compiler-cli and @angular/localize?

```
"@angular/compiler-cli": {
  "version": "12.0.5",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/compiler-cli/-/compiler-cli-12.0.5.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-XBZWU2S7N2kvQJK0H5KyLHiLVhYJrjh3NtbVBv67sCY9Ft8fv2jjbozTgXqeoYZ1xAxcZ2ZAB0n5SkhmY75Mow==",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ansi-regex": {
      "version": "5.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex/-/ansi-regex-5.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-bY6fj56OUQ0hU1KjFNDQuJFezqKdrAyFdIevADiqrWHwSlbmBNMHp5ak2f40Pm8JTFyM2mqxkG6ngkHO11f/lg==",
      "dev": true
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

```
"@angular/localize": {
  "version": "12.0.5",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/localize/-/localize-12.0.5.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-CRyXsNJYV7TJBsbG/Sn6lW9qMQCa+lw5SSNKHvnmfCTyd5p3DV8AdjOYkyWM5tfB4wg/aOc4C1ynDom4TmKv+w==",
  "requires": {
    "@babel/core": "7.8.3",
    "glob": "7.1.7",
    "yargs": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ansi-regex": {
      "version": "5.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex/-/ansi-regex-5.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-bY6fj56OUQ0hU1KjFNDQuJFezqKdrAyFdIevADiqrWHwSlbmBNMHp5ak2f40Pm8JTFyM2mqxkG6ngkHO11f/lg=="
    }
}
```

Comment: change version to the desired and do npm install? for install with specific version in params

Comment: @Vega do you mean change inside package-lock.json and run npm install ansi-regex@5.0.3?

Comment: Yes, either that, either npm install package_name@version_num

Comment: @Vega I updated my question. Can see if you are able to help? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean it will be overwritten? Delete node-module, change the version in package.json and run npm install. Or, just delete the package folder in node-modules and run npm install the ansi-regex@5.0.3